# generic function to convert Map to List in GO

Tags: go

How can I write a function in Go that would convert any Map to a List of object (dropping the keys) ?

For instance:

```
func mapToList(inputMap map[any]any) any {
    var resultList []any 
    for _, obj := range inputMap {
        resultList = append(resultList, obj)
    }
    return resultList
}

func main() {
    myMap := make(map[string]string)
    myMap["a"] = "1"
    myMap["b"] = "12"
    l := mapToList(myMap).([]string)
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", l, l)
}
```

would output: `([1 12], []string)`

But I always run into a type issue and didn't find a way around. Using type assertion or conversion I run into the similar issue.

```
cannot use myMap (variable of type map[string]string) as map[any]any value in argument to mapToList
```

How should I write the mapToList() function ?

It must take as an input `inputMap map[any]any` or `inputMap any` because I want to pass in any kind of map (map[string]CustomStruct; map[int][]CustomStruct, etc.)

Update: I added the function as I first write it and more more details on the input

Comment: What have you tried? Did you have a look at [Generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) yet?

Comment: @ojdo I update my question with my first try

Comment: The next version of Go (1.21) has a function to get the map values as a slice. View the source [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/99bc53f5e819c2d2d49f2a56c488898085be3982/src/maps/maps.go#L18-L26).  The function is available now in the  [golang.org/x/maps package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this tutorial on Generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) or [the language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations)

`any` is not the variable type, it is a `type constraint`, a description of the types that can be used. You need to define the type parameters with the constraint `any`, and then reference the generic types from within the parameter signatures.

```
//                                 | from this point on, K and V are
//                                 | now valid types to use in the function
func mapToSlice[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []V {
    s := make([]V, 0, len(m))
    for _, v := range m {
        s = append(s, v)
    }
    return s
}
```

The parameter `m` must be `map[K]V`, where `K` is a `comparable` type and `V` is `any` type. The return type `[]V` will be a slice of the same type used for the values in the input map.

Note that `any` can't be used as the constraint for the keys of the map, since not all types can be used as keys, only `comparable` types.

Then to call the method, you pass in a type that satisfies the constraints (eg `map[string][]string`), optionally making explicit the type parameters.

```
m := map[string][]string{
    "A": {"B", "C"},
    "D": {"E", "F"},
}
s := mapToSlice(m)
// or
t := mapToSlice[string, []string](m)
// [[B C] [E F]]
```

By making the type explicit, you can self-document your code and also catch any accidental type issues. For example, the following code will return an error:

```
v := mapToSlice[string, []int](m)
...
./main.go:14:33: cannot use m (variable of type map[string][]string) as map[string][]int value in argument to mapToSlice[string, []int]
```